# DropDown of JCombox is not shown

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox, that is generated in this way.

```
private JComboBox generateComboBox() {

    JComboBox ddl = new JComboBox();
    ArrayList<String> items = null;
    if(this.editable)
        items = (ArrayList<String>) Registry.getListEditable();
    else
        items = (ArrayList<String>)  Registry.getListNotEditable;
    for(String s:items)
        ddl.addItem(s);
    return ddl;
}
```

This ComboBox is displayed on the JFrame using that code here:

```
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.gridheight = 3;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        this.getRootPane().add(ddl_schemes,constraints);
```

The problem is, that the "dropdown" functionality is not visible. The ComboBox contains values and I am able to select those values using the arrow keys on my keyboard, but I cannot see the list.

Any suggestion?

Thank You!

Comment: Your username is ironic

Comment: For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Reimeus The plan is to get a JComboBoxMaster.... :-P... Just kidding, I just hadn't a better idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. So your problem maybe at any other point. Post more Code or a complete example.
Why you add all to the **rootpane**? Add it to the **contentpane**.

For more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

```
package testing;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JComboBoxMaster extends JFrame {

  private JComboBox generateComboBox() {
    JComboBox ddl = new JComboBox();
    List<String> items = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");

    for (String s : items) {
      ddl.addItem(s);
    }

    return ddl;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JComboBoxMaster jcbm = new JComboBoxMaster();
    jcbm.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    jcbm.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.gridheight = 3;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    JComboBox test = jcbm.generateComboBox();
    jcbm.getContentPane().add(test, constraints);

    jcbm.pack();
    jcbm.setVisible(true);

// This works
    test.addItem("four");

  }
}
```